# image can not be seen in htdocs in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: php, image, ubuntu, htdocs

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and recently have installed xampp 1.8.1. My problem is: images from server can not be shown which is look like as the following image :
[image: image not shown]

look here is in  my address bar I use **localhost/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/templet03.html** and I want to show image after **Unsung heroes** text but it only shown some link and not any image.

I use the following code for image ::

```
<div class="sideBlock unSung">
   <h4>Unsung heroes...</h4>
<a href="#"> <img src="_images/1_full.jpg" alt="Midnight Run" width="99" height="135" /> </a>

<a href="#"><img src="_images/2d7y3ki.jpg" alt="Wyatt Earp" width="99" height="135" /></a>
</div>
```

But when I use the following :

[image: image is shown]

look here is in my address bar I use **file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/templet03.html** and images are shown after **Unsung heroes** text.

After checking the permissions to access the directory where images are, I get this text in my terminal window ::

```
  sabbir@sabbir-pc:/opt/lampp/htdocs/madeTemplet/basicTemplet/_images$ ls -l
  total 300
 -rw------- 1 sabbir sabbir 204067 Feb 24  2010 1_full.jpg
 -rw------- 1 sabbir sabbir  75789 Nov 13  2009 2d7y3ki.jpg
 -rw------- 1 sabbir sabbir  23692 Apr 21  2010 6AB32AE44600435B9DE0FB5EBA24A912.gif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't have permission to change information. So you have to change permission of that folder. you can do as shown below::

```
1) **cd **

2) **cd /opt/lampp/htdocs**

3) **chmod 777 * -R**
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using `file:///` paths to address the images inside the HTML page. Don't do that; use the same protocol and host name you are using to serve the page, ie. `http://localhost`.

Access to local (`file://`) paths is usually restricted inside the browser for security reasons.

Comment: <img src="_images/1_full.jpg" alt="Midnight Run" width="99" height="135" />

Comment: what happens if you use the full file path in the img src?